# Test android program on non nexus emulators

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

i want test my android programs on non nexus emulators like Samsung mobiles or Sony or ...
but android device manager in  android studio only has nexus devices.
how i do it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Android emulator does not emulate "nexus devices", or "Samsung mobiles", or Sony devices. It emulates generic Android devices.

To help you set up Android emulators, the AVD Manager has you start with a "hardware profile". That is there to set up things like screen size and density, but that's about it. The AVD Manager ships with hardware profiles for Nexus-series devices. But:

- You can use the "New Hardware Profile" button to define any hardware profile that you want
- Some manufacturers, like [Sony](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/old-sdks/edk/edk-install/), offer dedicated hardware profiles that you can load into your SDK Manager
- Occasionally, a manufacturer may actually ship emulator images that can be used along with dedicated hardware profiles (Amazon used to do this, but doesn't when I last checked)